# Private channel works with static id but not dynamic vue.js

Tags: vue.js, pusher

On private channel when i hard coded the ID it works fine and i m receiving messages but when set the value to Dynamic it won't work.

Here is my app.js code

```
const livechat = new Vue({
   el: '#livechat',
   data: {
     conversation: [],
   },
   methods: {
     addMessage(message) {
       // Add to existing messages
       // this.conversation.messages.push(message);

       // Persist to the database etc
       axios.post('/messages', message).then(response => {
         this.conversation.messages.push(response.data);
       })
     }        
   },
   created() {
     axios.get('/messages/' + user_id).then(response => {
       this.conversation = response.data;
     });

     Echo.private('chat.' + this.conversation.conversation_id)
         .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
           this.conversation.messages.push({
             conversation_id: e.message.conversation_id,
             message: e.message.message,
             name: e.user.firstname
           });
        });
   }
});
```

On console log i m receving the **conversation_id = 22**

```
Echo.private('chat.22') //This works fine
Echo.private('chat.' + this.conversation.conversation_id) //This won't working
```

Broadcast file

```
public function broadcastOn()
{
    return new PrivateChannel('chat.' . (int)$this->message->conversation_id);
}
```

[image]

Is there any thing wrong in my code. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `this.conversation` is undefined until set in `then` handler. Put `Echo.private(...)` call in the same handler.

Comment: Perfect. I missed it. Thank you for your quick response...

Comment: Should I make this an answer?

Comment: yes. offcourse...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Echo.private` call should be done only when you have all the data - in other words, within `axios.get().then(...)`:

```
axios.get('/messages/' + user_id).then(response => {
   this.conversation = response.data;
   Echo.private('chat.' + this.conversation.conversation_id)
       .listen('MessageSent', (e) => {
         this.conversation.messages.push({
           conversation_id: e.message.conversation_id,
           message: e.message.message,
           name: e.user.firstname
       });
    });
});
```